# Developer story appears to show faulty dislikes, if left empty

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

If you leave the `Tech you dislike` field empty,

[image]

(Take note of the placeholder javascript, c#, php)

It translates into these 3 technologies you don't like:

[image]

Which I suppose should not happen, because I don't dislike them.

Comment: Yeah, I agree - we can do better here to make it clear that a) these are examples, not real data; b) maybe pick different copy/different examples rather than just those three.

Comment: @AdamLear dunno you, but php is fine there...

Comment: Looks like a pretty good default set to me.  :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no legitimate question. This was based on a misunderstanding of how placeholder text works.

Comment: Is that placeholder text shown to others as well? That would add *too much* confusion...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is just a placeholder, so you have something to hover over and bring up an "Edit" button. It doesn't appear on your [public-facing developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1249641) (view in an Incognito window). Note that your "Personal tech stack" will also show the "Javascript, php, C#..." placeholder text if left empty, but will be omitted when others view your story.

If you actually fill in a value, you'll see that the technologies are presented as tags, similar to the technologies you like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That was bugging me

Comment: That is a really awful placeholder.

Comment: I agree, i would think this is extremely obvious that it is only our default, not what shows to the public viewer.

Comment: Honestly, the placeholder text should be "I dlislike [tag:php]". No one would complain, or be taken seriously if they did complain, about that...

Comment: @TinyGiant yes but then people'd have the idea they don't need to actually go put PHP in there to have it visible to all. It should be *"you still need to add PHP here"*.

Comment: @user2357112: matches my dislikes so perfectly I thought it was customized ;)