# Rename Developer Story "disliked" tags to something neutral

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

The Developer Story page includes a list of preferred tags under the heading "Personal tech stack", as well as a list of tags you would prefer not to work with, currently prefixed with ***I dislike***. In the traditional CV the latter set of tags was instead under the headline ***Tech you don't want to work with***, which is a much more neutral and professional way of expressing the sentiment to a potential employee. Please replace "I dislike" with a more neutral expression, such as ***I prefer not to work with***.

To elaborate a bit, my preferred tags include linux as well as a few programming languages I want to work with. My "non-preferred" tags are apple and windows, for the simple reason that I do not want to work in an environment that primarily uses Windows or Mac/iOS instead of Linux as their development stack. The old CV expressed this in a reasonable way. The new Developer Story implies I hate Apple and Microsoft and makes me look like the kind of person that writes M$ instead of MS, and simply comes across as unprofessional.

Comment: If you could sum up "generally try to avoid" in one neutral sort of word, what would it be? (honest question, open to changing it, but need to meet design constraints too)

Comment: @TimPost Does it have to be a single word? The best I could come up with was "I prefer not to work with", as it is a clean and direct way of expressing the purpose. A shorter alternative could be "I want to avoid", which is a bit less neutral but still better than "I dislike". If that is too long for the current prefix format, another option would be to change it to a heading - that would also lead to a cleaner separation from the list of preferred tags.

Comment: No, I dislike PHP and wish to tell the world.

Comment: @Will With PHP "dislike" doesn't feel strong enough - but to express your hatred for PHP, the "personal statement" part seems like a good fit ;)

Comment: @l4mpi I would hope most people can come up with a personal statement more constructive than listing the things they hate

Comment: @meagar Hate is a powerful emotion.  Let it flow through you.  And at PHP.

Comment: @meagar thanks for reminding me that sarcasm doesn't work well on the internet, added a smiley to convey that the statement shouldn't be taken too seriously.

Comment: That was quick, @TimPost

Comment: We're going to have a discussion about this, I can pretty clearly see your perspective here and I don't disagree. I'll provide an answer once we've hashed it out.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336060/248058

Comment: What about renaming tags to something like `favour` and `disfavour`?

Comment: Why put it on there at all? Why draw attention to things you don't like?

Comment: @JMK To stop you getting contacted for PHP jobs when you're not interested in working with it anymore. (As an example)

Comment: @Will maybe they should special-case PHP - if it's in your ignored tags, put it in a special "I hate" section. Nobody will mind.

Comment: I don't mind it the way it is now, but @Albzi 's suggestion would also be acceptable.

Comment: @TimPost Non-preferred?

Comment: Eschew? Avoid? Not interested?

Comment: I predict recruiters will just keyword scan.  "Dislike PHP" will match "PHP" in a simplistic keyword search and cause Will to get bombarded with PHP job offers.

Comment: @TimPost: Avoids.

Comment: @david25272 of course - why would you dislike a programming language you haven't used?

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Answer (score 19):

I actually like that it says *I dislike*. It lets me list technologies that are an absolute no-go for me.

Your suggestion of *I prefer not to work with* suggests that I would still work with them if necessary.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I suspect most of us have very little we are *absolutely* unwilling to work with. If you were offered $500,000/year for COBOL, would you really keep that as a show-stopper?

Comment: @NathanTuggy That could happen I suppose, in an alternate universe... In our current universe, it's far more likely that potential employers reach out to me to work with the technologies I've listed there, for a realistic wage, in which case I wouldn't want to be bothered with it. If your best counter-argument is a far-fetched situation, it's not worth a lot imho.

Comment: In my own case, I dislike PHP enough that I would certainly like algorithmic help avoiding it, but if I was given a solid offer for a PHP job with a salary significantly better than my current one, I'd have to think hard about turning it down. Sure, if it's only a few thousand a year more, or otherwise pretty insignificant, I don't mind much if it just doesn't show up. But simply ignoring anything with those tags is a bit much.

Comment: Once I had a 2x salary bump, but I had to use PHP. It was a fun time, but it ensured that the next time I'd need a 4x increase instead.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What part of "I dislike PHP" implies that I wouldn't work with it for 500k/year?

Comment: @AntP: This answer argues that that's what it *should* mean ("absolute no-go"). I am arguing that it *shouldn't*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy that point doesn't really support the case presented in the question, though. "I dislike x," already doesn't mean "I absolutely won't work with x," so there's nothing there to suggest that "dislike" is too strong in that sense (I realise that the answer made that inference first - maybe I should have directed the comment at the answerer).

Comment: @Stijn Or, more commonly, reach out to you with a job offer about technologies you're interested in, and then try to load on extra job duties a bit later on in the job related to those languages you hate.

Answer (score 11):

Since people seem to use the non-liked tags differently, maybe it would be better to allow user customization of that particular field, so you could decide whether those are absolutely no-go technologies, or ones where you might be okay touching it once every two years.

Although once done like this I can imagine a a new feature request to allow sorting of disliked tags based on how much you hate them.

Comment: If the non-liked tags are used differently then that defeats their purpose for people reading them.

Comment: Or two separate fields, one for "please no" and the other for "NO NO NOOOOO!!!" :)

Answer (score 4):

You could simply leave it blank. If you "prefer not to work with" something then you obviously don't dislike it do you?

I "prefer not to work with" Objective-C or Ruby on rails but I specifically "dislike" php. I will leave out saying anything negative about Ruby on rails because I get great offers. I put up with it like I will with bad parking for the right pay at the right company.

As a dev, recruiters will toss anything at you to try to match you somewhere. So letting them know we dislike it, prevents (maybe only slightly lowers) some of the spam. And for those that are serious, like an actual hiring manager at the company itself, it could mutually save their time and yours as well.

Comment: I had some tech in the dislike part in my careers cv, but 60% of the offers I received were still related to those, so I don't think most recruiters would care :(

Comment: @SztupY great point, I edited my answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

We've updated the way we refer to these tags to be consistent with the traditional view and also to remove the emotion of "dislike".

The new headings are "I like working with" and "I prefer not to work with".

This is now consistent with the traditional view headings of "Tech you want to work with" and "Tech you don't want to work with".

Comment: Why didn't you go for something like what SztupY suggested [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336061/rename-developer-story-disliked-tags-to-something-neutral/336100#336100)? As is obvious by the voting and discussion here, it was not at all a unanimous sentiment.