# Non-preferred technologies are not visible from a recruiter point of view

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently got multiple offerings for technologies which included the tech I marked as *Tech I don't want to work with*.

At first I thought the recruiter didn't read my profile and vented a bit (shame on me) but then one recruiter told me he doesn't even see the *Tech I don't want to work with* content.

Screenshot from recruiter:

[image: The Technologies section lists Preferred technologies and Top percentiles.]

Screenshot from my point of view:

[image: The Technologies section has Non-preferred technologies above Top percentiles.]

It may be a bug or a missing feature, but none the less, it would improve the quality and the quantity of offers I get (and I assume a lot of others too).

Comment: "This candidate prefers to work with: anything that's not PHP"

Comment: This has to be a bug. What point would there be for this feature if it doesn't do anything? Just in case you forget that you hate PHP?

Comment: Temp fix: Just update your name to Sebastian "Hates PHP" L

Comment: Somewhat related: [Rename Developer Story “disliked” tags to something neutral](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336532/1114)

Comment: They don't need to know you hate PHP, they know that already, everybody hates it

Comment: @NickA You mean, everybody who hasn't evolved since the 00's?

Comment: PHP is the Internet Explorer of programming. The whole reason I learnt C/Python/JavaScript was because of how much I hated PHP. At the time PHP was the only language I knew. Imagine being so shitty that you're the only one around and you're still not wanted.

Comment: The PHP hate makes me both laugh on the inside but also cry since its still the only server-side programming language that I have experience with.

Comment: @user7393973 Learn flask or move to Node.js

Answer (score -1):

This is by design. At the moment we don't have any plans to change that functionality but I've updated the question with the feedback tag which gets periodically reviewed.

Comment: In light of this apparently-inscrutable decision, can you at least explain what is the intended purpose of this "non-preferred technologies" feature, if no relevant party is able to see it?